# HTML CSS Table positioning within a div

Tags: html, css

I have the below working example which I need tweaking slightly:

As you can see there are two centre aligned Tables. With a list of vertical buttons below left aligned.

The tables can have different numbers of `<tr>`'s and I want the tables to be equally aligned at the top not from the bottom. I.e. I want no gap at the top of the table 2. Does anyone know how I can amend this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/gg30jgh5/16/

HTML

```
<div id="lse" class="display">
  <div id="centertbl">
    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">Data 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">Data 2</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>

    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">Data 1</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 1">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 2">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 3">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 4">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.TSS {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: none;
  font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#centertbl {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `.TSS` class:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

I have added it to your code below; try running it:

```css
.TSS {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: none;
  font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#centertbl {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="lse" class="display">
  <div id="centertbl">
    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">Data 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">Data 2</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>

    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">Data 1</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 1">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 2">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 3">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 4">

</div>
```

Comment: Aaah fantastic! Thanks!